# How to show the actual user photo and if he doesnt have show unknown photo

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql

I´m trying to show the actual photo of the user that is logged in and if he doesnt have one shows the unknown photo.

I have some code already done, but I´m having problems with showing the actual user photo or the unknown photo if he doesnt have one already (desconhecido.jpg), and updating the table, as creating a file in the image folder (imagens_utilizador), for example if the user_id = 1 the user photo needs to be 1.jpg.

```php
<!-- Photo box that shows the actual photo and able the user to change it -->
<div class="col-md-5" align="center">
    <div class="text-center" align="center">
        <div align="center">
            <!--     <img src="/images/desconhecido.jpg" id="blah" height="140" width="140" /> -->
            <img src="/images/imagens_utilizador/<?php echo $row['fotografia']?>" id="blah<?php echo $row['idlogin']?>" height="140" width="140" />          
        </div>
        <br>
        <h6>Select one photo...</h6>
        <br>
        <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload" onchange="readURL(this,<?php echo $row['idlogin']?>)">
        <?php
            if (isset($_SESSION['imagem_demasiado_grande'])) {
                echo '<p style=" color:#F00; font-weight:bold"">Ficheiro demasiado grande! Tente novamente com outro ficheiro com tamanho inferior a 500KB.</p>';
                unset($_SESSION["imagem_demasiado_grande"]);    
            }
            if (isset($_SESSION['tipo_imagem_errada'])) {
                echo '<p style=" color:#F00; font-weight:bold"">Tipo de ficheiro errado! Tente com ficheiros do tipo ".jpg; .bmp; jpeg".</p>';
                unset($_SESSION["tipo_imagem_errada"]); 
            }                           
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This details and code aren't enough, please add more details about how your images are stored in the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before showing image check if image field is not empty.

```
<!-- Photo box that shows the actual photo and able the user to change it -->
<div class="col-md-5" align="center">
    <div class="text-center" align="center">
        <div align="center">
            <!--     <img src="/images/desconhecido.jpg" id="blah" height="140" width="140" /> -->
<?php if($row['fotografia'] != ''){ ?>
                <img src="/images/imagens_utilizador/<?php echo $row['fotografia']?>" id="blah<?php echo $row['idlogin']?>" height="140" width="140" />      
<?php } else{ ?>  
<img src="/images/imagens_utilizador/default.jpg" id="blah<?php echo $row['idlogin']?>" height="140" width="140" />       
<?php } ?>
        </div>
        <br>
        <h6>Select one photo...</h6>
        <br>
        <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload" onchange="readURL(this,<?php echo $row['idlogin']?>)">
        <?php
            if (isset($_SESSION['imagem_demasiado_grande'])) {
                echo '<p style=" color:#F00; font-weight:bold"">Ficheiro demasiado grande! Tente novamente com outro ficheiro com tamanho inferior a 500KB.</p>';
                unset($_SESSION["imagem_demasiado_grande"]);    
            }
            if (isset($_SESSION['tipo_imagem_errada'])) {
                echo '<p style=" color:#F00; font-weight:bold"">Tipo de ficheiro errado! Tente com ficheiros do tipo ".jpg; .bmp; jpeg".</p>';
                unset($_SESSION["tipo_imagem_errada"]); 
            }                           
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
```